# How do we read or create a cookie from a safari extension that could be used across many website pages on the same browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari, manifest

I saw a couple of posts from 2010 asking this question, things may have changed. How do we read or create a cookie from a safari chrome extension that could be used across many website pages on the same browser. Assuming that it was created on X.com and i still want to the same cookie to be available on Y.com

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you cannot share cookies across domains.

Let me know if you own both domains. Maybe in that case something can be figured out.

Comment: No, I do not own the second domain. I see, what i am trying to accomplish is to either  use cookies across domains or storage, while building a chrome extension, it is possible to achieve using `sync` eg `chrome.storage.sync.set({"myKey": foo})`. Now i am looking for a way to accomplish the same thing on a safari extension, do you have any idea if such a thing exist or is possible?

Comment: According to this document here...
[storage.sync - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/sync)

Safari 14 provides partial support for storage.sync. Although, Safari 15 on iOS offers complete support.
Lemme know if it helps! Cheers